# Insert checkboxes into database

Tags: php, mysql

** UPDATE **

I have updated my code BUT still no joy in getting the join table to update

I have three tables:

```
docs
  doc_id
  doc_name
  doc_content
cat
  cat_id
  cat_name
  cat_color
  cat_icon
cat_doc_join
  id
  cat_id
  doc_id
```

I currently have the ability to create and insert data into my docs table, it inserts the doc_name and doc_content into the table just fine. I have introduced categories into the new_doc.php form which shows an array of the categories available which can be selected via a checkbox. As it stands I am unsure on how to amend my insert query to take the id of the doc I am creating and the id of the selected checkboxes I have selected and then go on to not only insert into the docs table but also insert a row(s) into the doc_cat_join table if one or more categories had been selected:

Here is the script which handles the insert:

```
    <?php
require ('../../db_con.php');

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

// FORM VALIDATION & SUBMISSION
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $errors = array(); // BEGIN AN ERRORS ARRAY

    // CHECK FIRST NAME
    if (empty($_POST['doc_name'])) {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter a document name.';   
    } else {
        $dn = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['doc_name']));
    }

    // CHECK LAST NAME
    if (empty($_POST['doc_content'])) {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter any document content.';   
    } else {
        $dc = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['doc_content']));
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {

        // MAKING THE QUERY

        $q = "INSERT INTO docs (doc_name, doc_content, created_date) VALUES ('$dn', '$dc', NOW() )";          

        $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

        if ($r) { 

        $cat_ids=isset($_POST['cats'])&&is_array($_POST['cats'])?array_keys($_POST['cats']):array();

        $query='INSERT INTO cat_doc_join (cat_id,doc_id) VALUES';

        $length=count($cat_ids); 

        for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){ 
            $query.='('.$cat_ids[$i].','.$doc_id.')'; 

        if($i<$length-1) 
            $query.=','; 

        }

        mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

            // REDIRECT BACK TO DOCUMENT LIST
            echo("<script>location.href = 'list_doc.php';</script>");

        } else {

            // ERROR CHECKING!
            echo '<h1>System Error!</h1> <p>you could not be registered because of a system error!<br></p>';             

            // DEBUGGIN MESSAGE
            echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br><br>query: ' . $q . '</p>';
    }

        mysqli_close($dbc);
        exit();

    } else {

        // REPORT THE ERRORS
        echo '<h1>Error!</h1><p class="error">The Following error(s) have occured:<br>';
        foreach ($errors as $msg) {
            echo " - $msg<br>\n";
        }
        echo '</p><p>Please try again!.</p><p><br></p>';

    }

}
?>
```

And here is the section of the form which is an array of the categories:

```
<?php

$q = "SELECT * FROM cats";  

$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.

echo '<div class="view_body">';

// FETCH AND PRINT ALL THE RECORDS
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
echo '<br><input type="checkbox" name="cats['.$row['cat_id'].']"> '.$row["cat_name"]. '</label>';
}
echo '</div>'; 

?>
```

I guess what I am seeking advice on is how from the checkboxes I can include a value which is the cat_id and also within the INSERT query to add in the join table to insert into too.

Comment: how about inserting while you loop through array?

Comment: @user3113490 Would you be able to show me an example of how you mean sorry?

Comment: I'm back, $doc_id is not defined in your code...

Comment: I am in the same position as before :( Really struggling to get this to insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

echo checkboxes like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
    echo '<br><input type="checkbox" name="cats['.$row['cat_id'].']"> '.$row["cat_name"]. '</label>';
}
```

and use it like this (I suppose `$doc_id` is known, `doc_id` and `cat_id` are ints and the `id` field of your `cat_doc_join` table is autoincremented):

```
$cat_ids=isset($_POST['cats'])&&is_array($_POST['cats'])?array_keys($_POST['cats']):array();
//please check everything is fine here, they are ints, no sql injection,etc...
$query='INSERT INTO cat_doc_join (cat_id,doc_id) VALUES';
$length=count($cat_ids);
for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
    $query.='('.$cat_ids[$i].','.$doc_id.')';
    if($i<$length-1)
      $query.=',';
}
//run your query
```

**WARNING:** You'll have to sanitize your input to avoid SQL injection and stuffs

Comment: Ok brill, so in the second snippet your provide, where you have commented insert data what would that look like from my above example?

Comment: edited, I dindn't test and it could be more elegant, but I think it should work...

Comment: Hmm it seems to be killing the page now but with no errors? where would this code position itself in my snippet in my question?

Comment: Does this need to live just underneath my current INSERT INTO docs?

Comment: BTW if you don't see the error, it means you have not set `error_reporting` to `E_All`, which is useful for dev purpose...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81642/discussion-between-phpcoder-and-junius-rendel).

Answer (score 1):

```
 <form method = "post">
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="<?=$row["cat_name"];?>"/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="<?=$row["cat_name"];?>"/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="<?=$row["cat_name"];?>"/>
   <input type="submit" name ="cmd_submit"/>
 </form>


 <?php
     if(isset($_POST['cmd_submit'])){
        $arr_checkboxes = $_POST['checkboxes'];
        foreach($arr_checkboxes as $row){
           //do your insert code here.
        }
     }

 ?>
```

I haven't tried it. since I was not on my laptop.. but I think this will give you an idea. and assume that the checkbox is already wrap inside your loop.